# How do I call this method that is in a class?

Tags: python, class

I have this method printingpress, and I am trying to pass the argument hashtags[0].

I keep getting the error "1 required positional argument: 'keywords'. How do I fix this?

```
from time import sleep

from secrets import password, username

hashtags = [
'Modeling',
'Fitness',
'Travel'
]

class learning:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        print(username, password)
        sleep(2)

    def printingpress(self, keywords):
        print(keywords)
        #print(self)
learning(username, password)

learning.printingpress(hashtags[0])
```

Comment: You have to actually use the instance you have constructed instead of throwing it away. For example, ``learning(username, password).printingpress(hashtags[0])``

Comment: `learning(username, password)` creates an instance of the `learning` class but then immediately throws it away.  You need to save that to a variable, then call `printingpress` from that variable.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is in the last two lines of code. You created an instance of the class `learning` but did not assign it to any variable. And since `printingpress` method is not a static method of that class, it cannot be accessed directly using the classname. Instead you can do this:

```
from time import sleep

from secrets import password, username

hashtags = [
  'Modeling',
  'Fitness',
  'Travel'
]

class learning:
   def __init__(self, username, password):
     print(username, password)
     sleep(2)

   def printingpress(self, keywords):
     print(keywords)
     #print(self)

instance_of_learning = learning(username, password)

instance_of_learning.printingpress(hashtags[0])
```